# Outlook interop PrintOut document name

Tags: .net, printing, outlook, office-interop

We use Outlook interop method `MailItem.PrintOut()` to print a mail message from Outlook.
It is always printed with name "*Microsoft Outlook - Memo Style*".

"*Memo Style*" here is a print style which Outlook automatically picks for printing.
Is there any way to give a document any custom name so we can track it in printer queue?

It can either be **creating a new print style with custom name** or **explicitly specifying a custom document name**.

Basically, we just need emails printed from Outlook to appear in printer queue with unique names. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I hate that I don't have a virtual print server here at the house to check my hypothesis with, but doesn't emails list in the print queue as their respective Subject lines?

Comment: No, all of them appear in printer queue as "Microsoft Outlook - Memo Style"

Answer (score 1):

Well, [PrintSystemObject.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printsystemobject.name.aspx) is not settable outside the assembly, and unfortunately, I believe this is what you see when you view the windows print queue.  However, [PrintSystemJobInfo.JobName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printsystemjobinfo.jobname.aspx) does appear to be settable programmatically and may help you get what you need.

Comment: But I'm calling `void` Outlook interop method to print document. It doesn't return any information about printed document, only prints it with constant name. How can I determine which one of documents in print queue is mine?

Comment: Well, if all you want to know is what print job is yours, you can look at the owner of the print job. It'll have your network login name.

Answer (score 1):

The way to go to solve this is to look at your Printer's properties. I use Peernet's TIFF10 Printer and when I right-click the Printer Icon under Devices and Printers and click 'Printer Preferences', it gives me the option to choose filenames under the 'Save' tab. Check your printer's properties. It might have something

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by....

```
Mailitem.SaveAs(FilePathName) 'FILE NAME = NEW NAME
Mailitem.Printout()
```

Then you can simply delete the file you just created, or delete them all at once when you are done in a temp directory.